# Regex location /.* with nginx

Tags: nginx, location

I would like to deny all kind of URI like /.*
I try this but not mathing

```
  location ~* ^/\..* {
    deny all;
  }
```

When i try :

```
curl -H "Host: xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx" "http://localhost:8000/.env" -I
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Any idea to help ? I should have 401 and not...
Thx for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your URL is not captured by a location that has a higher priority?
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

The location block you specified for capturing periods (.) looks correct.
Also, deny will be 403, not 401.